# Angular 7 Change Detection: Problem with NgZone.onMicrotaskEmpty

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, angular-changedetection

I'm using chart.js in angular app and drawing the chart with the data coming from an API endpoint.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this._route.params.subscribe(p => {
  let id: number = +this._route.snapshot.params["id"];
  this.busy = this._awpsService
  .getOutcomeItem("years", id).subscribe(data => {
      this.years = data;
      this.selYear = this.years[0];

      this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first.subscribe(() => {
        $("#year").selectpicker();
        $(window).resize();
      });

      this.getProjectItems(id);

    });
});
}
```

The above code was working perfectly fine with angular 4 but after upgrading to angular 7, I had to change my code to

```
this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe(() => {
            $("#year").selectpicker();
            $(window).resize();
});
```

because `.first` is gone in angular 7. This has increased the CPU utilization and crashed the app. 
The `ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first` has been widely used in my app and I don't know how to hundle the change detection properly.I've also tried this way

```
this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.subscribe({
        next: () => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            $('#year').selectpicker();
            $(window).resize();
          });
        }
});
```

but no luck. anyone can help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: as a fact first still exists but it has to be in the pipe operator : 
this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.pipe(first()).subscribe( ... ) see https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/first.html

Comment: @FelixMovee Yes, you are right!